# Why I am getting 'Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders.' while a try to assign a const that a got from custom hook into another const using useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have made a custom hook that takes url and fetches the data in json format. But when I am trying to assign the data into const users using use state, I getting the error :
'Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop'

Here is the component from where I am trying to assign:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import useFetch from "./fetchData";
import Users from "./Users";
const ASSIGN5 = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useFetch(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
  );

  setUsers(data);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1 className="">Users Management App</h1>
      {isLoading && <p>Loading users...</p>}
      {error && <p>{error}</p>}

      <Search onHandleSearch={handleSearch} />
      {users && <Users users={users} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ASSIGN5;
```

And here is the useFetch hook:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isloading, setIsloading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw Error("Fetching unsucessful");
        } else {
          return res.json();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        setIsloading(false);
        setError(null);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error.message);
        setIsloading(false);
      });
  }, [url]);
  return { data, isloading, error };
};

export default useFetch;
```

But it runs fine when I use data directly without assigning but I need to because have to filter the data using functions

I am expecting that the data will assigned to the const users

Comment: Why did you decise to use `setUsers(data);` outside of useEffect, for example? If you do that just inside component function body - `setUsers` will cause a rerender. And with that - component's code will be re-executed. Causing calling `setUsers` again, which will again cause a rerender. And then again and again.

Comment: Could you show how do you use `useFetch`? It would be helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: @Mentlegen I am using useFetch to get the data by passing url

Answer (score 2):

Don't call state setters unconditionally in the component body or that'll trigger infinite renders.

It appears you don't need the `users` state at all because it's just an alias of the `data` array returned by your `useFetch` hook.

```js
const ASSIGN5 = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useFetch(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
  );

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1 className="">Users Management App</h1>
      {isLoading && <p>Loading users...</p>}
      {error && <p>{error}</p>}

      <Search onHandleSearch={handleSearch} />
      {data?.length && <Users users={data} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you want to rename it you can use

```js
const { data: users, isLoading, error } = useFetch(...);
// now you can replace `data` with `users`
```

`Search` and `handleSearch` weren't defined but I assume those are in your actual code somewhere.

Components are typically `PascalCase`, so `ASSIGN5` should be `Assign5`.